# object_definition does not display entire definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(m."object_id")
FROM sys.sql_modules m
```

and output results to text, the definition is truncated  for long definitions > 8192 characters. I have maximum characters displayed maxed out at 8192.This function is nearly useless if it cannot output a definition that runs past a small arbitrary limit of 8192 characters, so Microsoft probably thought of a workaround.

What is the (T-SQL, not GUI) workaround to show the entire object definition?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "T-SQL, not GUI". The issue is entirely with the GUI. TSQL has nothing to do with it. The language doesn't have extensions specifically to work around design decisions of SSMS.

Comment: Martin is correct, the 8192 limit is imposed by your current client (SSMS) and not by anything controllable by T-SQL.  The cheap and easy solution is to use a client that doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but you could use [sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith I see your point in a sense. So if I run the same query through a ADO.NET T-SQL command will I get truncated output or not?  Your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8930141/266457) works for this, btw.

Comment: @T.Webster - If you run the query through ADO.NET it won't be truncated. It is SSMS that truncates it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSMS for the above query, then do check the check below setting (Tools -> Options) in the SSMS where the number of charecters returned from the query to grid is controlled.

[image: Result to grid setting]