# is it possible to eliminate SSMS restriction on column length when not using Results to Grid?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm using `SQL Server 2014 Management Studio` to generate a text that will eventually be used to a file as you can see here:

```
SELECT 'begin' + REPLICATE(' ', 900) + 'end'--simplified for brevity
```

So there is a lot of blank spaces I need to write and I would like to use `Results to File` to create a `txt` file.

I ended up with the problem that `SSMS` truncate everything beyond about 300 characters.

In case I use `Results to Grid` I can't see the results without resize every time the grid but at least I can copy and paste them into a file.

Is it possible to remove this limitation for `Results do File` or `Results to Text` so I can see and output data with the same option?

**Edit**

I've already tried to [change the maximum column size for text](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/martinbell/archive/2009/10/25/How-to-display-long-text-in-SSMS.aspx) to 2048 but it did nothing.

**Edit 2**

Not a duplicate of [how to get the full resultset from SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930034/how-to-get-the-full-resultset-from-ssms) as **Les H** pointed out in comments because the problem there is the following:

> ... "results to grid" the data is encoded...

and

> ..."result to file" or "results to text" the text is limited to 8192
>   characters...

In my problem and even didn't hit the 8192 mark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the full resultset from SSMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930034/how-to-get-the-full-resultset-from-ssms)

Comment: @LesH Thanks for your help but not the same. See edit 2.